# Javascript Back Button for Referring Page, not History

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a standard PHP page that is accessed by multiple pages from multiple sites.

I'm using a standard history.back form element to take me back to the original page like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.back()">
  </input>
</form>
```

The issue is that if the person is interacting with the page for a period of time and then clicks the back button they may have to do so multiple times to actually get back to the original page that sent them here.

I considered hard coding the button to a specific page location BUT that is a problem b/c multiple pages feed into this single page where the user interacts with a form.

I cannot think of a way to redirect the user BACK to the actual page that they clicked on to visit the current page.

Comment: You could retrieve the referrer on the server side and store it in a field in the page. You can then go to that URL when the button is clicked. Alternatively, stop the URL being updated in the current page by calling `preventDefault()` on bookmark link clicks, and using `replaceState()` instead of `pushState()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that sounds like a winner, any chance you can put together an answer with example for me please?

Comment: Are you by chance using hash routing? Could we get an example of your url?